# Multiple RecyclerVIew adapter when restarting app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-recyclerview

I have a thread on MainActivity that will wait for a tcp response. When the thread get a response it will add the response into the adapter of recyclerview. When I build it for the first time there is no problem, but when I press the home button and open the app again, everything in the main activity seems restarting. the recyclerview doesn't display anything. After the tcp thread get a response and add the response into the adapter, the recyclerview won't display anything. When I try to get the data and print it on the log, it display different value depends on the location which inside of a thread and the other outside of the thread.

Here is my thread:

```
tcpHandler = new Handler(getBaseContext().getMainLooper());
tcpThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String response;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
        try {
            welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(8989);

            while(status)
            {
                Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader inFromClient =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

                response = inFromClient.readLine();
                Log.d("TCPCONNECTION", "receive "+ response);

                ArrayList<String> convert;
                try {
                    JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(response);
                    convert = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i<jr.length();i++) {
                        convert.add(jr.getString(i));
                    }
                    tcpHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setmAdapter();
                        }
                    });

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(!status){
                welcomeSocket.close();
            }
            tcpHandler.post(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});


tcpThread.start();
```

The method that adding the response into adapter:

```
void setmAdapter(){
    if(mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0)
    {
        ((CustomRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addItem(getDataSet().get(0),mAdapter.getItemCount());
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "Get Adapter: "+((CustomRecyclerViewAdapter) mAdapter).addItem(getDataSet().get(0));
    }else {
        mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());
    }
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private ArrayList<String> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(listResult.size() <= 0){
        results.add(0,"No Data Receive");
    }else {
        Data obj = new Data(recognizeResult.get(recognizeResult.size()-1).get(0));
        results.add(obj);
    }

    return results;
}
```

The output on my android monitor:

When build for the first time

```
TCPCONNECTION: receive [ "test1", "test2", "test3" ]
ADAPTER: Get Adapter: test1
TEST: onClick: test1
```

When I press the home button then relaunch the application

```
TCPCONNECTION: receive [ "index1", "index2", "index3" ]
ADAPTER: Get Adapter: test1
TEST: onClick: No Data Receive
```

I know its not a clean code, I just learn about thread and recyclerview and I want to test it out.

Comment: try this mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after following line mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: @VinitSaxena in my CustomRecyclerViewAdapter class I have a method that deal with it

`public void addItem(Data dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }`

Comment: Can you please try notifydatasetchanges method instead of notifydatainserted? Try this and let me know the result.